# Apache Camel SFTP Zero size file download

Tags: apache-camel, camel-ftp

I am downloading PDF file from server using camel SFTP component. Sometime it is downloading zero size file. but actual size is 4kb. I think camel is downloading the file while it is being written. kindly let me know how to download the file after file written operation is done. Give some example.

Comment: Please post your endpoint string (`ftp:...`) with all the options you are using.

Comment: sftp://username@hostname/path&binary=true&password=xxxx&download=true

Comment: after adding readLock=changed option in form URI, it is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding **readLock=changed** option in form URI, it is working fine

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it